# Database Products Table With Tiers

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database table called `Products` and `Tiers`

A `Product` belong to a `Tier`.

A `tier` can be:

1. Free
2. Intermediate
3. Expert
4. Enterprise

`tier`.`id` = 1 has all the Free products.

`tier`.`id` = 2 has all Intermediate AND Free products.

etc...

I'm using Sequelize in NodeJS to create my Models.  The big question I have is if I get `SELECT * FROM Tiers WHERE Id = 2`, I would want it to return both `Intermediate` and `Free` products.

Do I need a different table structure? New table? Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm not sure how to approach this tiered structure.

Comment: So, tier id 3 is expert and free?

Comment: @Strawberry Tier 3 would be Expert, Intermediate and Free.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I dont have knowledge on node.js, but seeing your query if you replace '=' with '<=' would work for you like

```
SELECT * FROM Tiers WHERE Id <= 2
```